# Geocoder search with autocomplete GeoJSON properties data in Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I'm using L.Control.geocoder to search my map by address and coordinates, but I wanted to do an autocomplete search using data from the GeoJSON properties.Nemesis file. Is it possible to add this functionality to the geocoder?

[image]

JS:

```
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder({
    position: 'topleft',
    collapsed: false,
    placeholder: 'Search...',
    defaultMarkGeocode: false,
})
geocoder.on('markgeocode', function(event) {
    var center = event.geocode.center;
    if(document.getElementById("divRadar") != null) {
        removeMarkerRadar();
    } else {
    }
    showMarkerRadar(center);
    map.flyToBounds(L.polygon([
        event.geocode.bbox.getNorthWest(),
        event.geocode.bbox.getSouthWest(),
        event.geocode.bbox.getSouthEast(),
        event.geocode.bbox.getNorthEast()
    ]).getBounds(), { maxZoom: 15 });
}).addTo(map);
```

GeoJSON:

```
"features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.224396,
                    38.706905
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "1",
                "L4": "OCICS",
                "n_ordem": "",
                "tecnico": "",
                "a3_crm_outros": "",
                "nemesis": "17DOI_SUBS064375",
                "a6_geca_af": "1032548843",
                "acl": "01MF01",
                "desig_trabalho": "Substituir poste de 8 metros",
                "morada": "Rua General Ferreira Martins, traseiras do nº 4 - Miraflores",
                "coordenadas": "38.706905, -9.224396",
                "data_entrega": "",
                "estado": "Suspenso",
                "data_producao": "",
                "data_policia": "",
                "observacoes": "Poste em terreno muito inclinado com acesso muito difícil, atrás de edifício. (fotos via email)"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.4152948,
                    38.711593
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "5",
                "L4": "OCICS",
                "n_ordem": "",
                "tecnico": "",
                "a3_crm_outros": "",
                "nemesis": "18DOI_SUBC119815",
                "a6_geca_af": "1032908299",
                "acl": "01CS01",
                "desig_trabalho": "Substituir cabo TPC, para o PD 600 (interior), por cabo  plástico  10 pares, e em simultâneo instalar cabo FO, para futuro PDO.. Duvidas, falar com César Fonseca.",
                "morada": "(GM)- Praceta Marqês de Soveral nº 81, Cascais",
                "coordenadas": "38.711593,-9.4152948",
                "data_entrega": "",
                "estado": "Suspenso",
                "data_producao": "",
                "data_policia": "",
                "observacoes": "11/11/2019-  CF Sim, é necessário tentar substituir o cobre e deixar guia para depois passar a fibra."
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.3772091,
                    38.7088777
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": "7",
                "L4": "OCICS",
                "n_ordem": "",
                "tecnico": "",
                "a3_crm_outros": "",
                "nemesis": "18DOI_SUBS120917",
                "a6_geca_af": "1032910014",
                "acl": "01ES01",
                "desig_trabalho": "Acondicionar correctamente rolos de cabo no poste e apear cabos RAD/drops desactivos.. Solicitação da CMC.",
                "morada": "(MJ)-Rua Vasco da Gama nº 58, Alapraia",
                "coordenadas": "38.7088777,-9.3772091",
                "data_entrega": "",
                "estado": "Suspenso",
                "data_producao": "",
                "data_policia": "",
                "observacoes": "Solicitei à VIATEL devolução"
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no such functionality included in the L.Control.geocoder control itself. You will have to use one of the JS autocomplete libraries for that. There are plenty, here is a list of some of them: https://www.cssscript.com/best-autocomplete/. This is then not GIS related question any more. If you'll have questions about using those libraries, you'll have to ask on StackOverflow site